# Incorrect video orientation in some browsers

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm using UIImagePickerController to capture a video then uploading it to a website. The problem is, if I record it in any orientation other than Landscape Left, the video shows up in a different orientation on every browser except Safari. So I believe this is a metadata issue.

Is there a way to re encode or rotate the entire video before or after the video is recorded?

```
UIImagePickerController *videoPickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                [videoPickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
                [videoPickerController setDelegate:self];
                [videoPickerController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
                [videoPickerController setMediaTypes:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil]];
                [videoPickerController setAllowsEditing:YES];

                [self presentViewController:videoPickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And to get the video I use

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    self.videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
}
```

Comment: Possibly add a code example.  People like to edit code here.

Comment: Just added a code example.